Printing tilted TPU model on Tina 2S
I'm new to printing with TPU and I have a specific model I'd like to print on my Tina 2S (from Entina). Here's my situation:

I want to print this CED7000 Shoot Timer CED7000.

Due to size constraints, I need to tilt the model about 30 degrees to fit it on the build plate.

Here is the slicing sequence of the model, which should give a better perspective on what I am trying to achieve.



My doubts are as follows:

Will it be feasible at all to print this tilted TPU model on a Tina 2S?
Will support removal be possible with this orientation and material?
What specific slicer settings would you recommend to increase the chances of a successful print and easier support removal?


Why don't you try it! I've printed many parts tilted, however, not in TPU. From the times I printed TPU I remember that bonding the first layer is important otherwise it becomes loose and the print fails.

@0scar will definitely give it a try, though I never printed TPU before, let alone tilted. It's looking like some 5 hours of printing, so I am keen to get as much info as possible before starting. At least, it looks like tilting will minimise the overhangs, which I also heard are pretty bad on TPU
